# How to alter relationship in MS SQL 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Database and I created a relationship between tables using Foreign Keys, I have (Devices) table and (Users) table and the relationship is one to many (1 - *) (one device can have many users), but I want to change this to be many to one (* - 1) (one user can have many devices) how to do that using T-SQL or using relationships design window? 
Regards

Comment: isn't it really a many-2-many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Delete your foreign key constraint on the users table

```
ALTER TABLE User
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_User_Device;
```

2) Delete the device_id column from users

```
ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMN device_id;
```

3) Add user_id column to device

```
ALTER TABLE device ADD user_id YOURIDDATATYPE;
```

4) Create foreign key constraint for user_id in device

```
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserID_Device FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES User (id) ;
```

Replace column names / data types with your data types.

Answer (score 0):

If it is many to one what you wanted (means one user many devices but one device only one user) then you can add one more column in device table refering to user table...

as what you have done for one to many relationship...
but revert of this